# how can get root page url in OnActionExecuting method while executing ajax request in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am executing a page where Page contain multiple Tabs and each tab call ajax method to get it's own view.

My problem is when ajax request come on controller then OnActionExecuting method I am not able to get Root(Page) URL.

Root URL like http://www.myapp.com/Profile/MyProfile
Ajax URL like http://www.myapp.com/Profile/ManageLocation

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
      var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
      string urlPath = url.Action();// Get current requested '/Action/Method'

//How to get Root Page URL

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get original URL from Headers collection:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var callFrom = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"];
        //Do something
    }
```